# Redux.js - I fail to mapStateToProps with React Redux - My React Component block on the store initial state and fail to update when store.state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying currently to pass the app.state contained to the Redux store in a React Component.

*So far, this problem is still a deep mystery...*

------>  [HERE THE GITHUB REPOSITORY OF MY CODE](https://github.com/Webman2000/client_update_word) <------

Hope it will help to figure out what is wrong.

**Abstract :**

My problem is basically about mapStateToProps, **is about link a Component to the state store**, AFAIK the rest work very fine, but ***Something seems shortcut my this.props in React's Component, because either I use connect() or delete the mapStateToProps method, my Component stil display the initial state ..!***

*Redux resists me like an end-level's boss...*

---

***STATE OF PLAY***

- The provider with a store of `react-redux`: OK
- Connect function pass to the props: OK
- mapDispatchToProps works fine! So why the state fails to update the props since the connection seems well established?

  - I know my action is well mapped since when I delete the mapDispatch in the connect composition, the component then fails to trigger the corresponding action.
- When console.log, the mapState receive effectively the store update but the Component stay blocked on initial state (tested with a "checkState" button on the component which returns the "store.getState().propertyTargeted"

***HINTS :***

- when I delete the mapStateToProps in connect, my React.Component continue to receive the initialState, 
  so maybe there is an another source that overwrites my mapStateToProps, I seek for it currently
- my this.props.state variable is called in the Component's constructor, maybe the constructor doesn't receive the store.updateState or something like that ? Another track to follow.

Here my combineReducer.js :

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import {post} from "./status"
import {entry}from "./updateState";

// only one reducer active 
const appReducer = combineReducers({ 
    entry,
    post

})
export default appReducer
```

Here my container.js :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

  return { word: state.entry.word }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
     postFile: postFileAction  
}

const PostFileContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component) ;
```

My postFile.js :

```
export const postFile = (word, base64Data) => dispatch => {
  console.log("postFile httpRequest reached")

  dispatch({
    type: 'POST_WORD',
    status: request
  });
  Axios.post("http://localhost:7500/api/files", {
      "word": word,
      "data": base64Data

    }, {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    })
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'POST_WORD',
        status: success,
        res
      }))
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'POST_WORD',
        status: error,
        err
      })
    });


}
```

Here in my store.initialState :

```
initial state: {
  "post": {},
  "entry": {
    "word": "initialWord"
  }
}
```

*the UPDATE_STATE_POSTWORD is provide by an other React component therefore dispatched to the store before that the bugging component trigger it own action with a updated word's entry.* 
Here my UPDATE_STATE_POSTWORD action snippet :

```
export const updateWord = word => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_STATE_POSTWORD,
    word
  };
}
```

/// reducers.js part ///

postReducer.js :

```
  export const post = (state ={}, action) => {

  console.log("postStatus reached - reducer")
    switch (action.status) {
      case request:
        console.log("Request start")
        return state
      case success:
        switch (action.type) {
          case POST_FILE:
            console.log("request succeed: ", action.res)

            var _id = action.res._id
            // var word= action.res.word
            return (Object.assign({}, state, {
              _id 
            }))
          case POST_WORD:
            console.log("request succeed: ", action.res)
            return (Object.assign({}, state, {
              _id: ""
            }))
          default : 
            console.log(`default state on success case in
                         postStatusReducer`)
            return state
      }
      case error:
        console.log("request error: ", action.err)
        return state
      default:
        return state
    }

}
```

entryReducer.js :

```
 const initialState = { word : "initialWord" }
 export const updateStateReducer = (state= initialState, action) =>
```

{

```
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_STATE_POSTWORD:
            var word = action.word
            return (Object.assign({}, state, {
                word
            }))
        default:
            return state

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do your actions look like?

Comment: Hi mccabridge I have edited my post in order to include the postFileAction

Comment: Did you add the reducer in combineReducer function?

Comment: thanks Murli yes the word is well updated in the store, is just about link my State to props

Comment: my reducer is updated by another action triggered in another component, the word is well updated, I can't figure out why my props.state does'nt update with the store

Comment: can you post the code of `combineReducer` part

Comment: @Murli Yep I have edited my post

Comment: I think the issue may be that you are mutating your reducer state. Post the reducer code

Comment: @Murli ok, I have edited my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173910/discussion-between-murli-prajapati-and-webman).

Comment: I have added all the repository of my code if it can helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-thunk`, your action fn would receive `dispatch` and `getState` functions as arguments.
Running getState would give you actual state of the application. Recuired data would be passed to reducer and so on.

In your example **RecordingAPI** receives props that comes from redux only while initializing - in constructor.
You can fix your component by adding **componentWillReceiveProps** method

```
class RecordingAPI extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        ...
        this.state = {
            word : this.props.word,
            state: this.props
        };
    }
    // new method that listens to props
    componentWillReceiveProps (props) {
        this.setState({
            word:   this.props.word,
            state:  this.props
        });
    }

    checkState(e){
        e.persist();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.dir(this.state.word)
        console.dir(this.state.state)
    }

    render() {
        ...

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={(e) => this.checkState(e)}>  CheckState </button> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean :/ if you can explicit your answer please, would be very appreciated

Comment: also I checked you code, it seems there is no action `UPDATE_STATE_POSTWORD`

Comment: thank for the review, I have updated my post. the UPDATE_STATE_POSTWORD is provide by an other React component therefore dispatched to the store before that the bugging component trigger it own action with a updated word's entry.

Comment: It would be useful to see action that triggers 'UPDATE_STATE_POSTWORD'. It not in your example yet.

Comment: Hi, can you explain where `word` comes from and briefly application flow

Comment: when you saying `mapState receive effectively the store update but the Component stay blocked on initial state` what component are you talking about?

Comment: I mean, my postFileContainer.js 's element receives effectively the store update but the ReactComponent.js stay blocked on the initial store.stare. I'm talkin about the AudioRecording.js

Answer (score -1):

My current work-around is to import the store directly in my React Component then subscribe to the changes as it :

```
import {store} from "../App" 

    store.subscribe(() => {
      // When state will be updated
      // we will update local component state and force component to rerender 
      // with new data.

      this.setState({
        word: store.getState().entry.word // new entry.words at each update in the statge of the React.Component
      });
    });
```

**ANSWER :**

Assigning the store.state value to the Component's state constructor, the Component failed to update the state. So, referring to the store.state using this.props outside any assignment to the Component.state.property works like a charm*. 
The trap is that storing a props in the `props.constructor.state` of the children works when you work only with React.js but this mechanism doesn't works for React-Redux then you have to stay the props outside any assignment in the `props.constructor.state`