# Javascript - It is possible to retrace the origins of a value of a Javascript variable with the dev.console?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with React Redux. Seems there is a overwritting of values in my code. My `this.props` of a connected (mapStateTo...) component come from an unknow part of my code.

My quest is directly linked to an another quest about [understanding why my React.Component doesn't update when the store.state updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51068191/redux-js-i-fail-to-mapstatetoprops-with-react-redux-my-react-component-block).

I'm trying to retrace currently the origins of the value in Javascript.  My console displays me the line of the code but not the origins of the `this.props` of my file directly in the console.

My problem is that I have a this.props but can't figure out to which part of my code it correspond.

On my console I have access to map.file but fail to find the origin  of my `this.props`, would be great if a method permit it.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by origins? You mean the line where it assigned `someObject.props = value;`?

Comment: Do you not understand the `this` part or the `.props` part? "My console displays me the line of the code" - does that mean you see an error? We might also need to know which browser.

Comment: no is not an error, it is the reverse, it is me that console.log() my value. I talk about, retrace from which file or part of my code the someObject.props arises from, like for the food, you retrace the origins of the food unti reach the craftman. To precise the context, I'm working with Redux and seems there is a conflict of this.props but I can't figure out from which part of my code

Comment: In MOST browsers if you see an error, you can click that in the console and it will go to the line of code referenced...

Comment: While I am still not 100% clear on your intent, perhaps lookup how to use the browser debugger in your specific browser, or perhaps `console.dir(myobject)` instead of `console.log(myobject)` might help?

Answer (score 1):

If the console displays the output, then enter to debug mode, put a breakpoint where you are printing and follow the execution stack trace, so you can see the code flow and where your prop has been initialized...

Comment: It is nice that you try to be helpful, but you are answering an unclear answer.
Your answer could also been have posted as a comment.
Scoring points is NOT the essence of SO.

Comment: I understood he couldn't see the origin of one of his initialized variable... so the simplest way I could see is by using the debugger. I don't understand what is the problem with my answer, really? Nothing to do with points btw...

Comment: yes meanwhile I have just put some stick, [importing my Redux.store directly in my React.component then subscribe to change in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51070872/9817602)